# Force a Click on a javascript page

Tags: javascript, code-injection

I have an HTML/JavaScript page and I need to force a hidden button to click.
The button is disabled until a video is finished playing
here is the source for the button

```
<TD valign=top align=center><a href="javascript:nextbutton();"
    onMouseOver="if (ITnext != null) document['continue'].src='skins/'+vidnextdown" 
    onMouseOut="if (ITnext != null) document['continue'].src='skins/'+vidnextup">
<img src='blank.gif' name='continue' border=0 width=72 height=72 alt='Next Topic'></a>
```

I have tried

```
$('/#continue').trigger("click");
```

and

```
javascript:$('/#nextbutton').trigger("click");
```

in the browser with no luck.

I am also forced to use Internet Explorer.

Comment: May I ask what you need it for? You having [tag:injection] and [tag:hack] tags on this question make it smell very fishy.

Comment: haha, because it kinda is that.  Every six months I have to spend 5 hours watching these interactive training videos, and the take a test.  I have the test answers memorized but don't have the time to sit through the very bad videos.  The next button will not load until the video is done.  So, while sitting here listening to these useless videos I have been trying to skip them.  I just want to force the nextbutton(); function to work so I can be saved from these awful videos...

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just execute the callback function for your onClick instead? You don't need to force the click event.

Comment: Yea I don't follow really,  read my comment above for a more clear idea of what I am trying to do

Comment: This will work. Simply call `nextbutton()` either by typing it into a console (which probably isn't possible due to IE), or by entering `javascript:nextbutton()` to the address bar.

Comment: yea I tried entering that into the address bar as well.  If I didn't have to used IE this may be a little easier.  It makes the video stop playing, which is nice since they are bad, but it does not skip to the next slide, it still waits for a few then allows me the click.  Even when the button is enabled it does not work.